# Chinese equivalent of the English word candid

Tags: word-choice, translation

I was just reading this news article and I'm interested to know which word or phrase would have been translated from Chinese to English as "candid":

> China's foreign ministry described Tuesday's talks as **"candid"** and
>   said the two sides agreed to keep discussing the issue, though
>   cautioned that responsibility for progress rests with Tokyo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Chinese equivalent of "candid" is "[坦白](http://www.zdic.net/cd/ci/8/ZdicE5Zdic9DZdicA6327541.htm)"(tǎn bái) or more formally "[坦率](http://www.zdic.net/cd/ci/8/ZdicE5Zdic9DZdicA6327544.htm)"(tǎn shuài):

> 中国外交部发言人洪磊表示，河相周夫与中国外交部副部长张志军之间的讨论是**坦率**和深入的。

(source http://www.voachinese.com/content/china-japan-20120925/1514644.html)

> 外交部副部长张志军与日本常务副外相河相周夫今早在北京举行钓鱼岛问题磋商，外交部在官方网站上发出新闻稿，以「**坦率**深入交换了意见」来形容这次会谈。

(source http://en.1688.com.au/site1/news/cn/2012/09/25/369457.shtml)